# Burninate [programming-competitions]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[programming-competitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-competitions) has 0 questions, 0 followers and no wiki summary.

In fact, it does not have anything.

Burninate?

Comment: Tags with no questions get auto-deleted

Comment: @Mat When do they get deleted?

Comment: Every 24h I think

Comment: @Mat I have been seeing that tag for 4 days and it did not have any questions.

Comment: Where are you seeing it?

Comment: @MikeM. When I searched for it, it was still there.

Comment: Well, you can put anything in [tag] form in the _Search..._ box, and it'll open a page for it, if that's what you mean: [\[abcdefg\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abcdefg). If you search on the [Tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), though, it doesn't show.

Comment: @MikeM. I searched for it here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags. You can see it by searching "competitions". The name of the tag is "competitions" but when I click on it, it redirects me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-competitions

Comment: I see [\[competitions\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/competitions), but not [programming-competitions]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e85fh.png.

Comment: Oh, yep, you're right. It redirects to [programming-competitions]. I guess the synonym is preventing [competitions] from being deleted?

Comment: BTW non-existent tags also show a "No results found" page like this: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/correct-horse-battery-staple

Comment: I removed the synonym there, now both shouldn't appear on the tag search. (cc @MikeM.)

Comment: Easiest burnination ever.